Models of a slice of coherent category
I am trying to get some sense of the proof of Theorem 10 in this link.
https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/278xnotes/Lecture6-Completeness.pdf
Immediately after it, Exercise 11 says a model of coherent category with a chosen point is equivalent to a model of the slice category.
May I please ask how precisely should I build this correspondence? Even just a quick construction without proof details reply would be appreciated. I would like to check it.

We have a coherent functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}_{/X}, Y\mapsto (\mathrm{pr}_2\colon Y\times X\to X)$, so if we have a model $M'\colon\mathcal{C}_{/X}\to\mathrm{Set}$ we get a model $M\colon \mathcal{C}\to\mathrm{Set}$ via compositon. The chosen element of $M[X]$ is induced by the diagonal map $X\to X\times X$ in the following sense: the diagonal $X\to X\times X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ is also a map $$(\mathrm{id}_X\colon X\to X)\to (\mathrm{pr}_2\colon X\times X\to X)$$ in $\mathcal{C}_{/X}$, and applying $M'$ to it gives us a map $*\cong M'[\mathrm{id}_X]\to M'[\mathrm{pr}_2\colon X\times X\to X]=:M[X]$. This selects the chosen element of $M[X]$.
Conversely, given a model $M\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathrm{Set}$ with a chosen element $m\colon *\to M[X]$, we can define $M'[p\colon Y\to X]$ via a pullback square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
M'[p\colon Y\to X]@>>> M[Y]\\
@VVV @VV{M[p]}V\\
* @>{m}>> M[X]
\end{CD}
$$
in $\mathrm{Set}$. You can check that $M'\colon\mathcal{C}_{/X}\to\mathrm{Set}$ is indeed a functor and coherent, and that these assignments define a bijection between the appropriate sets Lurie talks about. If you want details about this, let me know and I will edit them in.

Thanks a lot for this instant answer! May I please ask what is meant by the element of $MX$ is induces by the diagonal map? I would appreciate for more details because after seeing the construction, it is still not such clear to me that it is the obvious thing to do.

I edited in the definition of the chosen element of $M[X]$. When you ask for more details, do you mean you also would like more details about why in the second paragraph $M'$ as defined there is coherent and why we get this bijection between the sets Lurie talks about? Or was the definition of the chosen element of $M[X]$ the only thing? (It's fine in either case, but I can read your comment either way, which is why I ask for this clarification.)

Thanks so much! Let me try to unfold it and see if there is any outstanding confusion! If there remains unclear detail, I would comment here.
